# ODP.NET not recognized procedure in oracle package

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, package, odp.net

I have a simple package defined as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE wvParty IS
TYPE refParties IS REF CURSOR;
```

END wvParty;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY wvParty IS
    PROCEDURE proc_GetParties(
        p_party_name IN OUT VARCHAR2,
        x_party_info OUT refParties
        )
    IS
    BEGIN
        p_party_name := '%'||p_party_name||'%';

```
    OPEN x_party_info FOR
    SELECT party_id, party_number, party_type, party_name, 
        person_first_name, person_middle_name, person_last_name,
        known_as, known_as2, known_as3, known_as4, known_as5
    FROM hz_parties
    WHERE 1=1
    AND party_name LIKE p_party_name; 
END;
```

END wvParty;

It gets created in the oracle db with no errors.  In my code, I'm trying to call it using:

```
      try
  {
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_connStr);
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "wvParty.proc_GetParties";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    OracleParameter partyName = new OracleParameter();
    partyName.ParameterName = "p_party_name";
    partyName.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
    partyName.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
    partyName.Value = "Bubba";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(partyName);

    OracleParameter refParties = new OracleParameter();
    refParties.ParameterName = "x_party_info";
    refParties.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
    refParties.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(refParties);

    OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Yet, when I do I get the error:

PLS-00302: component 'PROC_GETPARTIES' must be declared.

So I'm at a loss.  I've created the proc as part of the package, I've declared it as I believe I should but I'm having little success resolving this.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the C# side of things, but there are a some problems on the Oracle side, like:

1. `proc_GetParties` is defined in the package body, but is not declared in the package specification.  This means that it's not visible outside the package body.  This explains why you are getting the `PLS-00302` error.
2. The `1=1` condition is not needed in the `WHERE` clause.
3. Do you really want to change the value of `p_party_name` within the procedure and have that change to be visible to the caller?  If not, it might be better to leave `p_party_name` unchanged and change the `LIKE` condition to `party_name LIKE '%' || p_party_name || '%'`.